# Unable to make API request to Plaid

Tags: curl, plaid

I'm trying to make figure out what's wrong with my flutter API call to Plaid, so I tried using `curl` to isolate the issue. I'm having an issue with Plaid unable to understand my JSON body. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the body. I used a JSON validator to make sure it was a valid JSON and it is.

```sh
curl -X POST https://sandbox.plaid.com/link/token/create -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8" -d '{"client_id":"CLIENT_ID","secret":"SECRET","user":{"client_user_id":"unique-per-user"},"client_name":"Plaid App","products":["auth"],"country_codes":["US"],"language":"en"}'
```

Comment: Can you provide the response as well as the request so we can see what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your request exactly as written, except substituting in my own client_id and secret, and it worked. Can you confirm that your CLIENT_ID and SECRET values are correct and available to curl?